# Object with two values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was looking through some code and I saw this:

```
if (player.info.admin < 1337)
```

I understand that this checks if the player admin level is below 1337, but I didn't know you could add two values (or whatever they're called, I'm learning) together.

For what I've learned, I would've done the following code like this:

```
var player {
     admin: 1337
}
```

And my if statement would be like this:

```
if (player.admin < 1337)
```

How do I do something like the first code? What's the reason to do it? Or did the person who wrote the code simply do something like this?:

```
 var player {
         info.admin: 1337
    }
```

Comment: let player = {
  info: {
     admin: 341234524514
  }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add two properties at once. So if this was an assignment, you would not be able to do this and have it work:

```
var player = {};
player.info.admin = 1337;
```

That's because even though `player` is indeed an object, it does not have a property called `info`.

There are multiple ways to add that nested value, but the most frequent ones are:

```
var player = {
    info: {}
};
player.info.admin = 1337;
```

and

```
player.info = {
    info: {
        admin: 1337
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a nested object. Here's how it would be laid out in code:

```js
var player {
    info: {
        admin: 1337
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Are there any advantages to doing this? Or is it just a matter of organization?

Comment: More a matter of organization. If you want to learn JSON, you'll see nested objects all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Player will be an [Object] and Info will be an [Object] inside Player, admin will be a Property, so structure like this:

```
const player {
  info: {
    admin: 1337
  }
}
```

In this case you can use "const" instead of var. const will set an reference to the player [Object] and you can still edit it if you need.

If 1337 is an ID value, you can go deeper and in different structures:

```
const player {
  admin: {
    id: 1337
  }
}
```

Now you have an Admin [Object] with the id property, inside the player [Object]. You can access it as:

```
player.admin.id // The value will be 1337
```